# Create anonymous highscorelistor in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have simple game on Google Play and Apple App Store that I have created in Unity. Now I am thinking about creating a global high score, so if you are in top 10 for example you can enter a made up user name.

The thing is I do not want the users to sign in since I want the game to be easy to access. One user can also enter a new username each time a record is beaten. So you can for example have the first three positions.

In principle, the app should read the high score from database and one should be able to write to it with {userID, new_score}, but no data is connected to any particular user. I am used to work with Firebase, what would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks,
Erik

Answer (score 0):

Well, the fact that you don't have data connected to any particular user do not means that you can't store the highscores. Cause one user can beat himself.

So if your database (I don't know if it's realtime or firestore) knows which are the top scores, when a user (indpendently of his ID) beats the score threshold, you can give him the option to put a name on that highscore, and update your database with this new score.

I will also recommend to bind users with data, his highscore or the name it's using to register the highscore, but you can achieve the same result without it.

Comment: Yes, but I was also thinking about the security rules for firebase. They usually complain if you let anyone write to the database. Maybe I was unclear with that thought.

Answer (score 0):

You could try having a read and create only set of records, where write requires a valid anonymous auth key. I haven't tried that setup with Anonymous only auth before though.

Otherwise you could also try setting up a cloud function to validate and write the high score records.